# using malayalam font in C# textbox

Tags: c#, fonts, textbox

i have an app in c# having 2 textbox.When i select the first one and type i should get the malayalam font and when i select the other textbox, i should get the text in english. For this i set the font of first textbox to malayalam and font of second textbox to english-arial.
and when i run the program both the text box displays english letters when i type. By pressing alt+shft keys and swapping the input language, then both textboxe's inputs become malayalam. I want to type malayalam in one textbox and english in other textbox without swapping the input language using alt+shft

Thank you

Comment: A font it not the same as a language. Please clarify your thinking about both and about what you exactly want to achieve. Also, please explain what you have done so far and explain where in your code you are stuck (post the problem code with the question).

Comment: You may have to handle the enter event of the malaya textbox and set the locale, then reset it on the leave event

Comment: Can you show some stuff for that?

Comment: It doesn't have anything to do with fonts.  You are switching the keyboard layout by pressing Alt+Shift.  While it makes little sense for a user to switch his native language half-way through filling out a form, you can use the .NET InputLanguage class to switch the keyboard layout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to select malaya language on text box enter event and back to english language selection on leave event as below:

```
private void textBox1_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.Globalization.CultureInfo TypeOfLanguage = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("ms-MY");
    InputLanguage.CurrentInputLanguage = InputLanguage.FromCulture(TypeOfLanguage);
}

private void textBox1_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.Globalization.CultureInfo TypeOfLanguage = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-us");
    InputLanguage.CurrentInputLanguage = InputLanguage.FromCulture(TypeOfLanguage);
}
```

Hope that was helpful.